# Extract first two characters of a String in Java

Tags: java, string, computer-science

I got a java question which is Given a string, return the string made of its first two chars, so the String "Hello" yields "He".

If the string is shorter than length 2, return whatever there is, so "X" yields "X", and the empty string "" yields the empty string "".

Note that `str.length()` returns the length of a string.

```
public String firstTwo(String str) {          

 if(str.length()<2){
     return str;
 }
 else{
     return str.substring(0,2);
 }
}
```

I'm wondering is there any other way can solve this question?

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code? I guess if you felt the need you could make it a oneliner `return str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(0,2) : str;` but I don't feel that this really adds anything.

Comment: appriciate the beauty of simplicity...dont try to make the code complicated when simple solution works well.

Comment: @DanLowe—fixed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your code looks great! If you wanted to make it shorter you could use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
public String firstTwo(String str) {
    return str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: thx a lot for helping

Comment: Works like gem.

Comment: 23

Apache Commons Lang has a StringUtils.left method for this.

String upTo2Characters = StringUtils.left(inputStr, 2);